# How to create new excel file each time when I save DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, export

I have function in Python Pandas like below (it is sample):

```
def xyz():
    df = pd.DataFrame({"a" : [1,1,1]})
    TodaysDate = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    excelfilename = "raport_" +TodaysDate +".xlsx"
    df.to_excel(excelfilename, sheet_name="raport", index=True)

    return df
```

Every time I run above function the existing excel file gets overwritten but I need a new excel file to be created every time I run the function. How can I modify my function to do that in Python ?

Answer (score 1):

You can change `TodaysDate = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")` to `TodaysDate = str(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %X")).replace(":", "")` or `TodaysDate = str(TodaysDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S"))`

This will give you an additional Hour/Minute/Seconds for the creation of your excel. So unless you are running this function multiple times a second this should cover your needs.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work, I have error: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'raport_2022-06-01_16:23:52.xlsx'

Comment: DO you have other idea ? :)

Comment: You can replace the ":" by this - `TodaysDate = str(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %X")).replace(":", "")`

Comment: Oh yes @vovakirdan method will work, I've also updated the code to reflect this idea without the replace (whichever you prefer)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this. Depends on how many excel files you want to generate.

```
import random
excelfilename = "raport_" + str(random.randrange(9999)) +TodaysDate +".xlsx"
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can do in this way:

```py
def xyz(itr):
    df = pd.DataFrame({"a" : [1,1,1]})
    TodaysDate = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    excelfilename = "raport_" +TodaysDate + str(itr) + ".xlsx"
    df.to_excel(excelfilename, sheet_name="raport", index=True)

    return df

for i in range(9): #or smth another iteration
    xyz(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really use ArchAngelPwn's solution in my opinion. Applying random numbers might work but you still run the 1/1000 chance that one file will get overwritten. Also, you might not know which file belongs to which loop/run.

You could also save your file names in a list and check if it exists :

```
fn = []
def xyz():
    df = pd.DataFrame({"a" : [1,1,1]})
    TodaysDate = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    excelfilename = "raport_" +TodaysDate +".xlsx"
    temp = len(np.where((np.array(fn) == excelfilename)))
    fn.append(excelfilename)
    df.to_excel("raport_" +TodaysDate + "_" + temp + ".xlsx", sheet_name="raport", index=True)

return df
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because % in your excelfilename becase you are using %X.

Just change:

```
TodaysDate = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %X")
```

To:

```
TodaysDate = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H_%M_%S")
```

I have double checked and its worked on my side :))

For full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import time


def xyz():
    df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 1, 1]})
    TodaysDate = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H_%M_%S")
    excelfilename = "raport_" + TodaysDate + ".xlsx"
    df.to_excel(excelfilename, sheet_name="raport", index=True)

    return df


xyz()
```